# mat-select dropdown multiselect screen reader(NVDA) and accessibility issue

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular6, accessibility, angular-material2

Angular Material Mat-Select dropdown with multi select along with search textbox  on downarrow and uparrow  key press NVDA is not reading the option Labels and when i press Enter button its not even getting selected, below is the sample code url. Is this issue exists in angular material plugin?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-select-search

Comment: I have the same issue as you. Did you ever figure out a fix for it?

Comment: Any update here?